# how to get vw fonts to stop growing

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive, font-size

I'm trying to create a responsive webpage where the max-width of html is 1000px. All of my fonts are specified in terms of vw. Is there a way to stop the fonts from growing when the browser is expanded to over 1000px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use media queries

```
.dynamic-size-text {
    font-size: 30px;
  }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .dynamic-size-text {
    font-size: 10vw;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a @media rule:

```
.text-class {
    font-size: 0.2vw;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    .text-class {
        font-size: /* some fixed size */;
    }
}
```